# migrating evolution to thunderbierd and maildir format

Tags: thunderbird, maildir

By default, thunderbird stores in mbox fromat, when you use `Config Editor` and search for `mail.serverDefaultStoreContractID` you find out its value: `@mozilla.org/msgstore/berkeleystore;1` If you want to change type of storing messages for fasting such as evoluton you can change it to : `@mozilla.org/msgstore/maildirstore;1`

**My Question** is :

I need to migraye from evolution 3.x.x to thunderbird, however i changed to maildir format my thunderbird, i googled, most of documentations mentioned to `mbox format` , Do you have any suggestion for `maildir format` for both?

Comment: Doesn't evolution already use maildir format?

Comment: before evolution milestone 3.x.x used mbox format and before mbox, used sqlite....!